# Windows API function FindWindow returns always 0 when exe is executed within PHP exec() function

Tags: php, windows, api, exec, findwindow

I have made a command line app to do some tasks on the server. For example, it 'tracks' a window and send keys to it. I use the windows API function findWindow() to find the window. When i run the exe from the command line it is working great except when i run it from PHP with the exec() function. The FindWindow function returning always 0 (it cannot find a window handle), why? Is it running in a sandbox or something?

What can i do about this? Anyone?

Thank you for your answer.

Kind regards,
Erwin Haantjes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services do not have the ability to find windows in the foreground user session.  This is called [session-0 isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463353).

PHP runs under the web server which is (usually) running as a service, in a particular session/context.  Because of this, your findWindows() function will fail.

You can test this theory by calling PHP.exe to run your script from your own session's command line.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your info, i understand it. Maybe there is another way to do it, for example with a mutex (file)? A resistent application creates a shared mutex and waits for input, the executed exe by php writes to the mutex. The resistant app executes it. Is that possible when it running as service?

Comment: Absolutely.  The filesystem between services and everything else is shared.  You just need to set it up with the proper permissions so that whatever is executing PHP (the web server's account, IUSR under IIS) has read/write access.

Comment: Hmm (thinking again), just wonder if it is possible using a shared DLL. An app starts the dll and keep it resident and the exe started by php uses that dll. What about that?

Comment: The DLL 'brainwave' does not work. I think Windows starts a new copy of the DLL in session-0 (isolation) mode?

Comment: Can you provide some code?  Otherwise it is difficult to help you.